# PHP $_GET if statement not working

Tags: php, get

```
<?php
    if (empty(htmlspecialchars($_GET["default"]))) {
        echo 'Click to type...';
    } else {    
        echo urldecode(htmlspecialchars($_GET["default"]));
    }
?>
```

My code is malfunctioning. Instead of echoing "Click to type..." it does nothing. What is wrong? Thanks so much, I am a noob at PHP.

Comment: Do you have any `HTML` which is passing the `$_GET`? Also you should remove the `htmlspecialschars` in the validation, no point doing it twice if it is not empty.

Comment: why htmlspecialchars() only to test if it's empty? why not just `empty($_GET...)`?

Comment: Try: `echo $_GET["default"];` and see what it is.

Comment: Plus, the data in `$_GET` is URL-decoded by PHP already. (If you need to do it “again”, you might be sending double-encoded data for possibly no good reason in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
if (!isset($_GET["default"]) || empty(htmlspecialchars($_GET["default"]))) {
```

Do you have error_reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

Why the do you have htmlspecialchars inside your if? You don't need it if you think about it for a second.

The recommendation I can give you is to check your request with some debugging (var_dump on your $_GET or using xdebug).

You can also check your URL to see if you have something like `localhost/someaction.php?default=something&other_get_parameter=somethingelse&....`. If it's on a form you can use you can check on your developer tools in your browser.